# Entity Framework 5.0 composite foreign key to non primary key - is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5, poco

I am using Entity Framework 5.0.0.0 in a .net 4.5 console application and I have to access a database with two tables in it with a foreign key relationship between them like so:

[image: overview]

The odd thing about it is that the foreign key is between `B(Almost1, Almost2)` and `A(Almost1, Almost2)` not from `B(AId)` to `A(AId)`.  This is allowed by SQL server as `Almost1` and `Almost2` combined are unique and neither are nullable (on table `A` at least - on `B` they are as it is an optional relationship but that is by the by).

Here's some SQL for creating this situation:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[A](
    [AId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Almost1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Almost2] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_A] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [A_Constraint] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Almost1] ASC,
    [Almost2] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[B](
    [BId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Almost1] [int] NULL,
    [Almost2] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_B] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [BId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[B] ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_A_B] FOREIGN KEY([Almost1], [Almost2])
REFERENCES [dbo].[A] ([Almost1], [Almost2])
```

The thing is, it seems that it is not allowed by Entity Framework - is this the case or am I just not defining my model correctly?

Here is my c#:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
        MyAs = Set<A>();
        MyBs = Set<B>();
    }

    public DbSet<A> MyAs { get; private set; }
    public DbSet<B> MyBs { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var aEntity = modelBuilder.Entity<A>();
        aEntity.ToTable("A");
        aEntity.HasKey(a => a.AId);

        var bEntity = modelBuilder.Entity<B>();
        bEntity.ToTable("B");
        bEntity.HasKey(a => a.BId);
        bEntity
            .HasOptional(b => b.A)
            .WithMany(a => a.Bs)
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("Almost1", "Almost2"));
    }
}

public class A
{
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public int Almost1 { get; set; }
    public int Almost2 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; private set; }
    public void AddB(B b)
    {
        if (b == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("b");
        if (Bs == null) Bs = new List<B>();
        if (!Bs.Contains(b)) Bs.Add(b);
        b.A = this;
    }
}

public class B
{
    public int BId { get; set; }
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var ctx = new MyContext(@"connection string"))
        {
            ctx.MyAs.Add(new A { Almost1 = 1, Almost2 = 1 });
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

It throws an `InvalidOperationException` saying:

> The specified association foreign key columns 'Almost1, Almost2' are invalid. The number of columns specified must match the number of primary key columns.

If I ignore the `AId` column and instead make `Almost1` and `Almost2` a composite primary key, so my `OnModelCreating` method now looks like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var aEntity = modelBuilder.Entity<A>();
    aEntity.ToTable("A");
    aEntity.HasKey(a => new { a.Almost1, a.Almost2 });
    aEntity.Ignore(a => a.AId);

    var bEntity = modelBuilder.Entity<B>();
    bEntity.ToTable("B");
    bEntity.HasKey(a => a.BId);
    bEntity
        .HasOptional(b => b.A)
        .WithMany(a => a.Bs)
        .Map(m => m.MapKey("Almost1", "Almost2"));
}
```

It works, but I don't really want to do this as there is also a table (let's call it `C`) that relates to `A` in the traditional way by having an `AId` column and the foreign key is going from `C.AId` to `A.AId`.

Yeah, it's a bit weird I know - but is it possible to deal with this in Entity Framework?

Comment: Entity Framework doesn't support unique keys, and without those, it cannot model your foreign key, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, since EF doesn't support unique keys and other SQL objects. I ended up creating some scripts as embedded resources and have them execute as part of the seed process of the drop/create initializer.

Not sure if this will allow you to navigate between the objects in code, but it works pretty nicely to have the database get updated in one process.