# Mapping foreign key to non primary surrogate key column in EF code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, entity-framework-6

```
public class A    
{   
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual int Aid { get; set; }    

    public virtual ICollection<B> B { get; set; }    
}


public class B
{    
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]     
    public virtual int Bid { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [Required]           
    Public virtual string BName {get ; set}

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [Required]      
    public virtual int Aid { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Aid")]
    public virtual  A A { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<C> C { get; set; }    
}


public class C
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]     
    public virtual int Cid { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [Required]    
    Public virtual string CName {get ; set}    

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [Required]          
    public virtual int Bid { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("Bid")]
     public virtual  B B { get; set; } 
}
```

relationship  between B and C is troubling me  .I dont want to include BName as foreign key in Class C

> Error : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles
>   in a relationship constraint must be identical

I understand the error but I want to point to C class only by Bid ,how I can achieve it without disturbing the relationship between A and B.

Answer (score 28):

This question is tagged for EF6.  But if you find this searching for EF Core.  Can use [Alternate Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys).

From link:

> Alternate keys can be used as the target of a relationship.

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Blog)
            .WithMany(b => b.Posts)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.BlogUrl)
            .HasPrincipalKey(b => b.Url);
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public string BlogUrl { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

As far as I understand it is **not possible** to do it in EF code first with either attributes or fluent api:

- [Entity Framework 6.1.3 Mapping Foreign key to non primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037798/enitity-framework-6-1-3-mapping-foreign-key-to-non-primary-key)
- [Entity Framework 5.0 composite foreign key to non primary key - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344077/entity-framework-5-0-composite-foreign-key-to-non-primary-key-is-it-possible)
- [Entity Framework Code first mapping without foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498795/entity-framework-code-first-mapping-without-foreign-key)

But I can propose you to remodel your solution a bit - don't create a primary key on `B(BName, Aid)` - make it an unique index - [Unique Key constraints for multiple columns in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889218/unique-key-constraints-for-multiple-columns-in-entity-framework).

```
public class B
{    
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]     
    public virtual int Bid { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_B_Name_Aid", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    [Required]           
    Public virtual string BName {get ; set}

    [Index("IX_B_Name_Aid", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    [Required]      
    public virtual int Aid { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Aid")]
    public virtual  A A { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<C> C { get; set; }    
}


public class C
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]     
    public virtual int Cid { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [Required]    
    Public virtual string CName {get ; set}    

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [Required]          
    public virtual int Bid { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Bid")]
    public virtual  B B { get; set; } 
}
```

The index will give you the same performance benefits for querying as the primary key (though with a bit of additional overhead to support the primary [surrogate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) index over the `Bid` column).

Also, recommended reading - [Surrogate vs. natural/business keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63090/surrogate-vs-natural-business-keys).