# Custom foreign key column of source table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I would like to configure EFCore that `A` property of class `B` would be loaded based on property `AAlternateId` and `AAlteranateId` should be foreign key of table `A` of column `AlternateId`. How would I configure that using fluent api?

```
class A {
  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  public Guid AlternateId { get; set; }
}

class B {
  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  public AAlternateId { get; set; }

  public A A { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping foreign key to non primary surrogate key column in EF code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38029313/mapping-foreign-key-to-non-primary-surrogate-key-column-in-ef-code-first)

Answer (score 0):

First, you seem forget to set the type of `AAlternateId`.

```
public Guid AAlternateId { get; set; }
```

Then, if you want the ForeignKey `AAlternateId`  to be linked to `AlternateId` (which is not PK), you should use **PrincipalKey** to define the reference key `AlternateId` with a **unique restriction**.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<A>().ToTable("A");
    modelBuilder.Entity<B>().ToTable("B");
    modelBuilder.Entity<B>()
        .HasOne(b => b.A)
        .WithOne()
        .HasPrincipalKey<A>(a => a.AlternateId)
        .HasForeignKey<B>(b => b.AAlternateId);
}
```

And the result:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[B] (
[Id]           UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
[AAlternateId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_B] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_B_A_AAlternateId] FOREIGN KEY ([AAlternateId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[A] ([AlternateId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Hi @Puchacz, can this solution help you solve the problem, if so, you can mark it as answer, thanks:)